# Autopostgresqlbackup - DBEXCLUDE doesn't works

Tags: postgresql, backup, automation

I'm trying to exclude some databases using the DBEXCLUDE option,but there's daily backups anyways.

```
# ===============================
# === Debian specific options ===
#================================

# By default, on Debian systems, only 'postgres' user
# is allowed to access PostgreSQL databases without password.
# In order to dump databases we need to run pg_dump/psql
# commands as 'postgres' with su.
#
# The following setting has been added to workraound this issue.
# (if it is set to empty, 'su' usage will be disabled)
SU_USERNAME=openerp

#=====================================================================
# Set the following variables to your system needs
# (Detailed instructions below variables)
#=====================================================================

# Username to access the PostgreSQL server e.g. dbuser
USERNAME=openerp

# Password
# create a file $HOME/.pgpass containing a line like this
#   hostname:*:*:dbuser:dbpass
# replace hostname with the value of DBHOST and postgres with 
# the value of USERNAME

# Host name (or IP address) of PostgreSQL server e.g localhost
DBHOST=localhost

# List of DBNAMES for Daily/Weekly Backup e.g. "DB1 DB2 DB3"
DBNAMES="all"

# pseudo database name used to dump global objects (users, roles, tablespaces)
GLOBALS_OBJECTS="postgres_globals"

# Backup directory location e.g /backups
BACKUPDIR="/var/lib/autopostgresqlbackup"

# Mail setup
# What would you like to be mailed to you?
# - log   : send only log file
# - files : send log file and sql files as attachments (see docs)
# - stdout : will simply output the log to the screen if run manually.
# - quiet : Only send logs if an error occurs to the MAILADDR.
MAILCONTENT="quiet"

# Set the maximum allowed email size in k. (4000 = approx 5MB email [see docs])
MAXATTSIZE="4000"

# Email Address to send mail to? (user@domain.com)
MAILADDR="root"

# ============================================================
# === ADVANCED OPTIONS ( Read the doc's below for details )===
#=============================================================

# List of DBBNAMES for Monthly Backups.
MDBNAMES="template1 $DBNAMES"

# List of DBNAMES to EXLUCDE if DBNAMES are set to all (must be in " quotes)
DBEXCLUDE="DrFabioGonzalez","DraLuisaFPaez","DraMariaVRomero","DraNhoraOrtiz","DraMyriamRamirez","Entrenamiento","GastroCenter","PsicologiaFUAC"

# Include CREATE DATABASE in backup?
CREATE_DATABASE=yes

# Separate backup directory and file for each DB? (yes or no)
SEPDIR=yes

# Which day do you want weekly backups? (1 to 7 where 1 is Monday)
DOWEEKLY=6

# Choose Compression type. (gzip or bzip2)
COMP=gzip

# Compress communications between backup server and PostgreSQL server?
# set compression level from 0 to 9 (0 means no compression)
COMMCOMP=0

# Additionally keep a copy of the most recent backup in a seperate directory.
LATEST=no

# OPT string for use with pg_dump ( see man pg_dump )
OPT=""

# Backup files extension
EXT="sql"

# Command to run before backups (uncomment to use)
#PREBACKUP="/etc/postgresql-backup-pre"

# Command run after backups (uncomment to use)
#POSTBACKUP="/etc/postgresql-backup-post"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other values and comments like *DBNAMES* suggest the syntax is a single pair of double quotes around a space separated list of DB names:

```
DBEXCLUDES="DB1 DB2 DB3"
```

Which is a syntax easy to handle for shell scripts.

Comment: I have implemented the changes as mentioned lets give a try thank in advance